# MySQL count values from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two identical tables - logins and visits. Which contains:

```
ID | address | mac_address | date
```

How can I make a php query to count logins and visits from mac address kind of this:

```
MAC | Logins | Visits
```

For now I have

```
SELECT mac_address, COUNT(mac_address) AS login_cnt FROM logins GROUP BY mac_address ORDER BY login_cnt DESC
```

which gives me just

```
MAC | Logins
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    mac_address,
    SUM(logins_mac_count) AS logins_mac_sum,
    SUM(visits_mac_count) AS visits_mac_sum
FROM (
        SELECT mac_address, COUNT(*) AS logins_mac_count, 0 AS visits_mac_count
        FROM logins
        GROUP BY mac_address
    UNION
        SELECT mac_address, 0 AS logins_mac_count, COUNT(*) AS visits_mac_count
        FROM visits
        GROUP BY mac_address
) AS t
GROUP BY mac_address
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(logins.mac_address, visits.mac_address) AS unique_mac_address,
    COUNT(login.mac_address) AS count_logins,
    COUNT(visits.mac_address) AS count_visits
FROM logins
LEFT JOIN visits ON logins.mac_address = visits.mac_address
GROUP BY unique_mac_address
```

Note: I haven't tested this as I don't have your schema/test data here, but I think this should work. Let me know if not.

Comment: This will miss any mac address in `visits` which doesn't appear in `logins`.

Comment: True, thanks for the hint @Jim. Maybe a `SELECT ( SELECT UNION ) GROUP BY` then?

Comment: I think a `SELECT UNION` won't help either, as it will sum up the vistis + logins counts. As far as I get it, he needs these values to be distinct.

Comment: @Jim: it depends on the OP's logic. If all mac_addresses are in visits table (since visit happens before login), then this should work, but `FROM` should be from table visits, and `JOIN` from logins.